# MySQL Job failed to start after adding "log = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log" to my.cnf

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add `"log = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log"` to my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file. But after `sudo service mysql restart` I have `Job failed to start`.

If I delete line `"log = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log"` all work fine.

Set permissions like `sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql`

What it can be?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with sw development, this is pure admin stuff. DBAs are in a lot better position to answer such questions.

Comment: @Shadow I must add tags associated with DBA or what?

Comment: No, there is a separate DBA site within the stackexchange network, that's where you are supposed to ask your question. SO is for sw development related questions.

Answer (score 0):

Just change this

`log = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log`

to this

`general_log_file  = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log`